# bitmap size exceeds on mapview addoverlay

Tags: android

I am adding overlay to map with some .png files. It works fine, but at sometime it throws Bitmap size exceeds VM Budget error. When this same problem occurred for adding image to listview, i solved it by applying SoftReference. But i don't know how to apply it for adding overlays in mapview. Any ideas please. Thanks

Adding overlay like this

```
public ItemizedOverlayMarker(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}
```

Call the ItamizerOverlay like this :

```
final List<Overlay> mapOverlaysResult = mapView.getOverlays();
Drawable drawableResult = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_pink);
final ItemizedOverlayMarker itemizedoverlayResult = new ItemizedOverlayMarker(drawableResult, this);

for (int i = 0; i < Constants.listOfPlaces.size(); i++) {

    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(latitude) * 1E6), (int)(Double.parseDouble(longitude) * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, name, vicinity);
    itemizedoverlayResult.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                }
```

Comment: is there a outOfMemory error?

Comment: yes, outofMemoryError : bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Comment: can you past code for how image is loading from webURL and adding it on overlay

Comment: I edited with code, I used image only from drawable

Answer (score -1):

First convert image as File object

and pass on below function it will return bitmap..

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
    {
        try
        {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true)
            {
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```